# How come we can have color value first in box-shadow rule?

Tags: css, box-shadow

[The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) for box-shadow clearly states that the first option is for length value, and color value comes last.

How come than that the below works?

```css
box-shadow: #0000002e 0px 1px 2px;
```

```css
.style {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: #0000002e 0px 1px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="style"></div>
```

Comment: in that documentation *<shadow> = inset? && <length>{2,4} && <color>?* --> and for && --> *Separating two or more components, by a double ampersand, &&, means that all these entities are mandatory but may appear in any order.*

Comment: where you see that it *clearly states that the first option is for length value*?

Comment: True, not "clearly". But all examples shows that. But OK, I got it, the options can come in any order than?

Comment: yes, following the above syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is optional, you can put the `color` at the beginning or the end and it wouldn't be "incorrect".

In the documentation it states `<shadow> = inset? && <length>{2,4} && <color>`

Those `&&` separators mean that they're mandatory, but order is not important. The `?` for `inset?` and `<color>?` mean that those fields are optional.

The compiler sets the values based off the input type.